# Android: Update Fragment A when user hits back on Fragment B in Navigation Component, Single activity app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-navigation

I have the following requirement: Fragment A shows all referred friends from API call, which it calls onCreateView. The user can navigate from Fragment A -> Fragment B. In Fragment B the user can refer new friends. When the user refers a friend I make an API call and trigger activity.onBackPressed() to pop Back to Fragment A.

On return in Fragment A, I need to make the API call to get all referred friends to update the UI. Unfortunately neither onCreateView() nor onResume() nor onStart() are called when I pop back. How do I make the new API call and update the UI?

Fragment A:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
 super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(ReferAFriendViewModel::class.java)

viewModel.getRAFStatus().observe(viewLifecycleOwner,{
    //UpdateUI
})
```

}

Fragment B:

```
viewModel.postSendInvites(binding.etName.text.toString(), binding.etEmail.text.toString())

requireActivity().onBackPressed()
```

Comment: Can you share your code where you are calling the API in the fragment A?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your first fragment.

```
findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<Type>("key")?.observe(
    viewLifecycleOwner) {result ->
    // Do something with the result.
}
```

And in your second fragment.

```
findNavController().previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set("key", result)
```

I end up creating two extension functions for it.

```
fun <T> Fragment.getCurrentBackStackEntryLiveData(key: String): MutableLiveData<T>? {
    return findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData(key)
}

fun <T> Fragment.setCurrentBackStackEntryLiveData(key: String, value: T) {
    findNavController().previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set(key, value)
}
```

Here is the [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79672220#comment55) for the same.

Comment: It is not working with onBackPressed() inside fragment B. How to use it?

Comment: @ShyamalyLakhadive what do you mean?

Comment: this solution working fine with android.R.id.home. But I also want to implement it with onBackPressed() as the same action should be performed with onBackPressed() too.